# .htaccess RewriteEngine multiple pages same code

Tags: .htaccess

I want to obtain this via RewriteEngine:

```
mysite.com/translate/hola    referring to mysite.com/?goTo=translate&str=hola
mysite.com/buy/12            referring to mysite.com/?goTo=buy&id=12
```

How can I do this with one rule?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

ewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?goTo=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)